Lenovo Q21h-10 brightness setting gets lost when you suspend or turn off the display
When I use the OSD of the monitor to set Low Blue Light off and on, it significantly reduces display brightness. However, if I turn off display or suspend it, and later turn it on again, the display is very bright again. How can I retain moderate brightness and Low Blue Light effectively i.e. make it remember display brightness?
